# SAML 2.0 based Authentication for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, json, rest, restful-authentication, saml-2.0

Team, kindly help me how to implement SAML based authentication for iPhone application. I have .NET REST based JSON webservice as my backend service.

Kindly advice me on this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

There are existing standards and tools to support your requirement today. As Scott mentioned, it does require either using the embedded browser in iOS within your application or allowing the iOS Safari Browser to handle the SAML/Browser portion of SSO (each has its own pros/cons). You can check out this free White Paper entitled, "[A Standards-based Mobile Application IdM Architecture](http://www.enterprisemanagement360.com/wp-content/files_mf/white_paper/exp_final_wp_mobile-application-idm-arch-8-11-v4.pdf)" that talks about how Ping (my employer) customers are handling this today if you'd like some more ideas.

Comment: The link doesn't work, here's the newer one:
http://www.enterprisemanagement360.com/white_paper/a-standards-based-mobile-application-idm-architecture/

Comment: Thanks, latest link found here: http://www.enterprisemanagement360.com/wp-content/files_mf/white_paper/exp_final_wp_mobile-application-idm-arch-8-11-v4.pdf

Comment: latest link: https://www.whitepapers.em360tech.com/wp-content/files_mf/white_paper/exp_final_wp_mobile-application-idm-arch-8-11-v4.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The SAML-only solution has properties that bother some due to the phishing risk of downloadable apps, but the mechanism involved is outlined at https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/ECP

Other approaches involve hybrids of OAuth or other technologies but you won't find any standards or tool support for any of this.