# SAML Authentication for a Javascript Mobile Application(Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, cordova, active-directory, saml

We have implemented a cross platform mobile application by using Phonegap.

App interacts with the database or any other resources on the server through oData services.

The services use SAML authentication to authenticate the user or to provide access to the requested resource.

Did anybody get a chance to work on SAML authentication from javascript.

Is there any open source component/framework/api which makes SAML authentication easier.

Thanks,
Venkat Malladi.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, SAML authentication does require a Service Provider (SP) and cannot be done exclusively from JavaScript. Refer : [SAML 2.0 based Authentication for iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997349/saml-2-0-based-authentication-for-iphone-application?rq=1)